# Decimal to hex in python

Tags: python, serial-port, hex

So I have kind of a ignorant (maybe?) question. I'm working with writing to a serial device for the first time. I have a frame [12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, X, Y] that I need to send. X and Y are checksum values. My understanding in using the pyserial module is that I need to convert this frame into a string representation. Ok that's fine, but I'm confused on what format things are supposed to be in. I tried doing

```
a = [12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, X, Y]
send = "".join(chr(t) for t in a)
```

But my confusion comes from the fact that X and Y, when using chr, transform into weird strings (assuming their ascii representation). For example if X is 36, chr(x) is '$' instead of '\x24'. Is there a way I can get a string representing the '\xnn' value instead of the ascii code? What's confusing me is that 12 and 7 convert to '\x0b' and '\x07' correctly. Am I missing something?

**Update:**
So it might be that I'm not quite understanding how serial writes are being done or what my device is expecting of me. This is a portion of my C code that is working:

```
fd=open("/dev/ttyS2",O_RDWR|O_NDELAY);
char buff_out[20]
//Next line is psuedo
for i in buff_out print("%x ",buff_out[i]); // prints b 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 9 b3 36 
write(fd,buff_out,11);  
sleep()
read(fd,buff_in,size);
for i in buff_in print("%x ",buff_in[i]); // prints the correct frame that I'm expecting
```

Python:

```
frame = [11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9] + [crc1, crc1]

senddata = "".join(chr(x) for x in frame)



IEC = serial.Serial(port='/dev/ttyS2', baudrate=1200, timeout=0)
IEC.send(senddata)

IEC.read(18) # number of bytes to read doesn't matter, it's always 0
```

Am I going about this the right way? Obviously you can't tell exactly since it's device specific and I can't really give too many specifics out. But is that the correct format that serial.send() expects data in?

Comment: From the Python documentation, chr() returns the number you enter into it as an ascii character. 12 and 7 in ascii are the bell and form feed 'characters', which python may not be able to print (don't know for sure). So it could be defaulting to hex representation for those since they're undisplayable.

Comment: Sorry I meant \x0c. I have another frame that starts with 11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's perfectly normal for ASCII bytes to be represented by single characters if they can be printed, and by the `\x??` notation otherwise. In both cases they represent a single byte, and you can write strings in either fashion:

```
>>> '\x68\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f'
'hello'
```

However if you're using Python 2.6 or later then you might find it easier and more natural to use the built-in `bytearray` rather than messing around with `ord` or `struct`.

```
>>> vals = [12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 36, 100]
>>> b = bytearray(vals)
>>> b
bytearray(b'\x0c\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x07\x00$d')
```

You can convert to a `str` (or `bytes` in Python 3) just by casting, and can index the bytearray to get the integers back.

```
>>> str(b)
'\x0c\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x07\x00$d'
>>> b[0]
12
>>> b[-1]
100
```

As to your serial Python code, it looks fine to me - I'm not sure why you think there is a problem...

Comment: +1 bytearray is a much more natural choice when dealing with strings of bytes

Comment: There's a problem because it works in C and not in python ;) I'll keep looking at it. The C is really complex so maybe I missed something

Answer (score 1):

The character with the ASCII-code 36 **is** `'$'`. Look it up in any ASCII table. Python only displays the hex escapes if the character is not printable (control characters etc).

At the lowest level, it's the same bit pattern anyway - no matter whether Python prints it as a hex escape or as the char with that ASCII value.

But you might want to use the [struct](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html) module, it takes care of such conversions for you.

Comment: I tried struct too. I guess I'm just not sure how the module wants me to give it data

Answer (score 0):

I would guess you want [struct](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html).

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.pack('>B', 12)
'\x0c'
>>> vals = [12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0xa, 0xb]
>>> ''.join(struct.pack('>B', x) for x in vals)
'\x0c\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x07\x00\n\x0b'
```

Comment: *Thouh shalt not use a list comprehension where a generator expression doth suffice.*

Answer (score 0):

What you do is perfectly fine: your `send` is what you want: a sequence of bytes with the values you want (`a`).

If you want to see what are the hexadecimal codes of the characters in `send`, you can do:

```
import binascii
print binascii.hexlify(send)
```

or

```
print ''.join(r'\x%02x' % ord(char) for char in send)
```

(if you want `\x` prefixes).

What you see when directly printing `repr(send)` is a *representation* of `send`, which uses ASCII: 65 represents 'A', but character 12 is '\x0c'.  This is merely a convention used by Python, which is convenient when the string contains words, for instance: it is better to display 'Hello' than \x48\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f!